# Node js jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have the following the code on aap.js with a route to '/bio_post'. I'm trying to post some text based on my website using jquery ajax. The problem I'm having is that jquery picks up the objects that come from '/bio_post' as undefined. I was wondering if you guys can point me in the right direction. Thank you for your time and effort.

```
app.post('/bio_post', function (req, res) {


    // Get user input value

    let update_bio = req.body.user_bio;

    // Check if the input isn't empty
    if(update_bio !== "") {

        // Connect to mysql database

        mysql_connection.query("UPDATE users SET user_bio = ? WHERE id = ?", [update_bio, session_id], function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                let obj_error = {err: err};
                res.send(obj_error.err);
            } else {

                // Check if the post was successfully inserted into the database
                if (rows.changedRows === 1) {
                    let id = {id: session_id};
                    res.redirect("/profile/" + JSON.stringify(id.id));
                    console.log("bio post id is: " + JSON.stringify(id.id));
                    /*let msg_success = {id: session_id, success_msg: 'Bio successfully inserted!'};
                    res.send(msg_success);*/

                } else {
                    let id = {id: session_id};
                    let msg_error = {msg_err: 'No changes were made to your bio.'};
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(msg_error.msg_err));
                    console.log("bio post id is: " + JSON.stringify(id.id));
                }

            }
        });
    }else{
        //res.render("settings", {u_id: session_id, logged_in_user: session_username, bio: '', bio_msg: "Bio field cannot be empty."});
        res.send("Bio field is empty");
    }
});
```

Below is the code for jquery.

```
/**Set up URL route variable**/

           let url = '/bio_post';

           /**Set up Ajax callback**/

           $.ajax({
               url: url,
               type: 'POST',
               data: {user_bio: user_bio.val()},
               success: function (data) {

                   if(data.msg_err){

                       success_bio_handler.hide();
                       error_bio_handler.fadeIn().text(data.msg_err).delay(5000).fadeOut();

                   } else {
                       error_bio_handler.hide();
                       //success_bio_handler.fadeIn().text(data.success_msg).delay(5000).fadeOut();
                       //window.location.href = '/profile/' + data.id;
                       console.log(data.id); /***COMES OUT AS UNDEFINED****/
                   }


               }
           });
```

Then lastly, is the html file.

```
<!--ADD OR UPDATE BIO-->

    <div id="add_update_bio_title"><strong>Add or Update Bio</strong></div>
    <div id="add_update_bio_panel">

        <form id="frm_add_update_bio" action="/bio_post" method="post"><br />
            <div class="py-5 w-100">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p id="error_bio_handler" class="alert-danger collapse">Error</p><!--jQuery error handler-->
                            <p id="success_bio_handler" class="collapse" style="background-color: #00AA88; color: white;"></p><!--jQuery success handler-->
                            <form class="">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <!--Check if user has entered a bio-->
                                    <div class="alert-danger"><%= typeof bio_msg !== 'undefined' ? bio_msg : '' %></div><br />
                                    <% if (bio){%>

                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="user_bio" name="user_bio" placeholder="Write a little something about yourself"><%- bio%></textarea>

                                    <%} else{%>

                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="user_bio" name="user_bio" placeholder="Write a little something about yourself"></textarea>

                                    <%}%>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"></div>
                                <div class="form-group"></div>
                                <button id="btnSubmitBio" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add or Update Bio</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--END ADD OR UPDATE BIO-->
```

Comment: Well, you are redirecting the Ajax request after successful insertion, I don't think that can work 

Comment: Oh I see. So, that's why it comes out as undefined because it's being redirected and ajax can't find anything? Lol

Comment: So I assume, I haven't tried running your code. Try actually returning something using `res.send`, and then do the redirect on the client side.